# ExecutorService terminated, but the JVM did not

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I submit some tasks to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)`, they all run and complete successfully. Then I call

```
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

check it via

```
executorService.isShutdown()
executorService.isTerminated()
```

and get twice true back. The main thread exits, but the JVM stays alive. There's no AWT thread or alike, all I can see are the 3 pool threads, `DestroyJavaVM`, and `com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer`.

The Finalizer could be the prime suspect, if it wasn't a deamon thread. I suspended two threads to get this image

[image: godot]

Actually, I'd expect the pool threads to be long gone, because of `isTerminated == true`. Any idea who are they all waiting for?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another service running somehow? I see that this is pool-2.

Comment: @dcernahoschi Me stupid... I just forgot to add [`@Singleton`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git-history/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Singleton.html) to my wrapper around the service. So I shut down one pool and the other stayed. Maybe I should delete this questions, however, someone else may profit from it as I could have. Mind you adding an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your debug image that your service is not alone as it's named `pool-2`. So you might have another `ExecutorService` still running as `pool-1` that prevents the JVM to exit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to call executorService.shutdownNow() to close the service properly after awaitTermination(..).

Also you should be calling System.exit(..) which would terminate your JVM eventually.

Comment: I've tried `shutdownNow()` already, no help. Sure, `System.exit` works, but doesn't feel right.